# Projectiles Image Error Problem How To FIx?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pygame

so I am trying to make my projectile into images instead of circles but I am getting this error

```
 File "C:\Users\Habib\Desktop\PYTHONGGAME\py.py", line 353, in <module>
   bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
TypeError: __init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

my projectile class

```
class projectile(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.toxic = pygame.image.load("toxic.png")
       self.rect  = self.toxic.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       window.blit( self.toxic, self.color, self.rect )

   def moveTo(self, x, y):
       self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
```

showing the projectile class on screen

```
   if keys[pygame.K_a] and shootLoop == 0:     
       for bullet in bullets:
           if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
               bullet.x += bullet.speed 
           else:
               bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
       if len(bullets) < 2:  
           bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
   if keys[pygame.K_d] and shootLoop == 0:     
       for bullet in bullets:
           if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
               bullet.x -= bullet.speed 
           else:
               bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
       if len(bullets) < 2:  
           bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
```

my full Code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
slash1 = pygame.image.load("slash.png")

lefts = [pygame.image.load("Sprite-0001.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0004.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0005.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0006.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0007.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0008.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png")

        ]
toxics = pygame.image.load("toxic.png")

stand = pygame.image.load("stands.png")


rights = [pygame.image.load("Sprite-50.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-51.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-52.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-53.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-54.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-55.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-56.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-57.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-58.png")


        ]

right = [
           pygame.image.load("enemy.png"),
           pygame.image.load("enemys1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys4.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys5.png")
           ]

class projectile(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.toxic = pygame.image.load("toxic.png")
       self.rect  = self.toxic.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       window.blit( self.toxic, self.color, self.rect )

   def moveTo(self, x, y):
       self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )



# the enemy
class enes:
   def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,end):
       self.right = [
            pygame.image.load("enemy.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys4.png"),
            pygame.image.load("enemys5.png")]
       self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.right]
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.path = [x,end]
       self.walkCount = 0
       self.walk_so = 0
       self.so_walk = 0
       self.speed = 3
   def draw(self,window):
       self.move()
       if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
           self.walkCount = 0
       if self.speed > 0:
           window.blit(self.right[self.so_walk//3], (self.x,self.y))
           self.walkCount += 1
       else:
           window.blit(self.right[self.so_walk//3],(self.x,self.y))
           self.walkCount += 1
   def move(self):
       if self.speed > 0:  
           if self.x < self.path[1] + self.speed: 
               self.x += self.speed
           else:
               self.speed = self.speed * -1
               self.x += self.speed
               self.walkCount = 0
       else: 
           if self.x > self.path[0] - self.speed: 
               self.x += self.speed
           else:  
               self.speed = self.speed * -1
               self.x += self.speed
               self.walkCount = 0
   def hitbox(self):
       print('hit')
goblin = enes(100,280,64,64,200)
goby = [goblin]



# color for enems
green = (63, 190, 22)
enems1 = enes(350,259,50,50, green)
florida = [enems1]

# player class

class player:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height  = height
       self.width = width
       self.speed = 5
       self.isJump = False
       self.JumpCount = 10
       self.fall = 0
       #hit box
       self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)
       self.stand = pygame.image.load("stands.png")
       self.lefts = [
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0001.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0004.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0005.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0006.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0007.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0008.png"),
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png")
        ]
       self.rights = [
       pygame.image.load("Sprite-50.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-51.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-52.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-53.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-54.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-55.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-56.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-57.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-58.png")
        ]
       self.rights = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.rights]
       self.lefts = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*4,image.get_height()*4)) for image in self.lefts]
       self.stand = pygame.transform.scale(self.stand,(self.stand.get_width()*4,self.stand.get_height()*4))
       self.bo_index = 0
       self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
       self.anim_fps = 400
       self.anim_index = 0
       self.stans_index = 0
       self.direction = "right"
       self.direction = "left"
       self.direction = "standing"

       self.rect = pygame.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width, height)
   def draw(self):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

       if self.direction == "left":
            player_image = self.lefts[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.lefts):
                self.anim_index = 0
       elif self.direction == "right":
           player_image = self.rights[self.anim_index]
           self.anim_index += 1
           if self.anim_index == len(self.rights):
               self.anim_index = 0
       else:
           player_image = self.stand

       player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
       player_rect.centerx += 10 # 10 is just an example
       player_rect.centery += -20 # 15 is just an example
       window.blit(player_image, player_rect)





# platforms
class platform:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.color = color
       self.plat = pygame.image.load("gt.png")
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,plat.get_width(), plat.get_height())
       self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.plat,(self.plat.get_width()//2,self.plat.get_height()//2))
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
   def draw(self):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       window.blit(self.plat,self.rect)

# Coins
class coin:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.coinss = pygame.image.load("coin_gold.png")
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,coinss.get_width(), coinss.get_height())
       self.plat = pygame.transform.scale(self.coinss,(self.coinss.get_width()//2,self.coinss.get_height()//2))
       self.color = color
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
   def draw(self):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       window.blit(self.coinss,self.rect)


# Floor
class floor:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.color = color
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
   def draw(self):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
score = 0
text = font.render('Gold  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()  
textRect.center = (100, 40)

# enemy
Sfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
Kills = 0
Stext = Sfont.render('Kills  = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRectS = Stext.get_rect()  
textRectS.center = (400, 100)


# fps
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
Green = (63, 190, 22)
Blue = (22, 190, 175)
white = (240, 240, 240)

# define the enemy player coin classes
playerman = player(150,350,30,30, Blue)
enemy1 = platform(150,390,190,10, Green)
enemy2 = platform(300,310,190,10, Green)
enemy3 = platform(80,260,190,10, Green)
enemy4 = platform(250,180,190,10, Green)
enemy5 = platform(490,120,190,10, Green)
enemy6 = platform(-50,100,190,10, Green)
enemy7 = platform(180,50,190,10, Green)
platforms = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,enemy5,enemy6,enemy7]

# coin class
coin1 = coin(180,320,150,150, Green)
coin2 = coin(350,250,50,50, Green)
coin3 = coin(150,200,50,50, Green)


Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3]

# floor class
floor1 = floor(-1000,490,9999,50, white)
flories = [floor1]
# shoot the enmey loop
shootLoop = 0
if shootLoop > 0:
   shootLoop += 1
if shootLoop > 3:
   shootLoop = 0
#main loop
bullets = []
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
   clock.tick(FPS)
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           runninggame = False


   if playerman.y < 250:
       playerman.y += 1
       for platform in platforms:
           platform.y += playerman.speed
       for coin in Coins_list:
           coin.y += playerman.speed
       for floor in flories:
           floor.y += playerman.speed
       for enes in goby:
           enes.y += playerman.speed






   if playerman.y > 450:

       playerman.y -= playerman.fall
       for platform in platforms:
           platform.y -= playerman.fall
       for coin in Coins_list:
           coin.y -= playerman.fall
       for floor in flories:
           floor.y -= playerman.fall
       for enes in goby:
           enes.y -= playerman.fall




   keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
   playerman.direction = "standing"

   if keys[pygame.K_a] and shootLoop == 0:     
       for bullet in bullets:
           if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
               bullet.x += bullet.speed 
           else:
               bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
       if len(bullets) < 2:  
           bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))
   if keys[pygame.K_d] and shootLoop == 0:     
       for bullet in bullets:
           if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
               bullet.x -= bullet.speed 
           else:
               bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
       if len(bullets) < 2:  
           bullets.append(projectile(round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2), round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2), 6, (0,0,0)))





   if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
       playerman.direction = "right"
       playerman.x -= playerman.speed
       if playerman.x < 100:
           playerman.x += playerman.speed
           for platform in platforms:
               platform.x += playerman.speed
           for coin in Coins_list:
               coin.x += playerman.speed
           for enes in goby:
               enes.x += playerman.speed


   if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
       playerman.direction = "left"
       playerman.x += playerman.speed
       if playerman.x > 400:
           playerman.x -= playerman.speed
           for platform in platforms:
               platform.x -= playerman.speed
           for coin in Coins_list:
               coin.x -= playerman.speed
           for enes in goby:
               enes.x -= playerman.speed




   if not playerman.isJump:
       playerman.y += playerman.fall
       playerman.fall += 1
       playerman.isJump = False
       collide = False
       for platform in platforms:
           if playerman.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
               collide = True
               playerman.isJump = False
               playerman.y = platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
               if playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                   playerman.x = platform.rect.left - playerman.width
               if playerman.rect.left < platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                   playerman.x = platform.rect.right


           for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
               if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                   del Coins_list[i]
                   score += 1
                   text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                   textRect = text.get_rect()  
                   textRect.center = (100, 40)





       for floor in flories:
           if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor.rect):
               collide = True
               playerman.isJump = False
               playerman.y = floor.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
               if playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.left - playerman.width:
                   playerman.x = floor.rect.left - playerman.width
               if playerman.rect.left < floor.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor.rect.right + playerman.width:
                   playerman.x = floor.rect.right





           if playerman.rect.bottom >= 490:
               collide = True
               playerman.isJump = False
               playerman.JumpCount = 10
               playerman.y = 490 - playerman.height

           if collide:
               if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                   playerman.isJump = True
               playerman.fall = 0


   else:
       if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
           playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
           playerman.JumpCount -= 1
       else:
           playerman.JumpCount = 10
           playerman.isJump = False

   window.fill((74, 107, 104))
   goblin.draw(window)
   window.blit(Stext,textRectS)
   for bullet in bullets:
       bullet.draw(window)
   window.blit(text,textRect)
   for platform in platforms:
       platform.draw()
   for coin in Coins_list:
       coin.draw()
   playerman.draw()
   for floor in flories:
       floor.draw()



   pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `projectile` has the arguments `x`, `y` and `color`

> ```py
> class projectile(object):
>   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
>       # [...]
> ```

When you create an instance of `projectile`, then you pass 4 rarguments:

> ```py
> bullets.append(
>    projectile(
>        round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2),
>        round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2),
>        6,
>        (0,0,0)))
> ```

In the previous version of the projectile, there was an additional `radius` argument:

> ```py
> class projectile(object):
>    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color):
>        # [...]
> ```

Remove the radius (6), when you create and instance of projecctile:

```py
bullets.append(
    projectile(
        round(playerman.x+playerman.width//2),
        round(playerman.y + playerman.height//2),
        (0,0,0)))
```